# How do I get the duration of an HTML5 video that has been loaded dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm loading an HTML5 video with Ooyala script and trying to get the duration value of the video.  I get this error "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined".  Here's my code:

```
var video = jQuery('.video-element').get(0);
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
    var minutes = parseInt(video.duration / 60, 10);
    var seconds = parseInt(video.duration % 60);
    var secondsnew = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);

    console.log(minutes+":"+secondsnew);
});
```

I assume this is because the video is being loaded in dynamically because I've tested with a native video already loaded in the DOM and it worked.  How do I make this work with a dynamically loaded video?

Comment: From the error, it seems like the video component doesn't exist in the DOM or you're not selecting it correctly. Did you inspect the DOM after the script executed to ensure that it exists?

Comment: @MaxSindwani Yes it definitely shows in the DOM.  I even changed `.video-content` to `video` to target the actual `<video>` tag.  I even tried wrapping everything in `jQuery(window).load()` but then I didn't get anything in the console log.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to access it using **Ooyala** script but from simply `HTML5` video can be access by `js` using video Id

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var videoDuration =  document.getElementById('Sample')
    var duration = videoDuration.duration;
    alert(duration);
};
```

HTML

```
<video src="video.mp4" id="Sample" controls>
      video not supported
</video>
```

Comment: We can only assume by what OP has provided is that one or more video elements have a class `.video-element`, Therefore, you should probably offer a solution that is suited to work with one or multiple videos. Nevertheless +1.